# PHP:Server side radio button validation

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am new to php OOP

Currently I am using the following code to validate a form on the server side.

The files that are used in this case are:

register.php:

```
<form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="first name" value="<?php echo Input::get('fname'); ?>" name="fname" autocomplete="off" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="last name" value="<?php echo Input::get('lname'); ?>" name="lname" autocomplete="off" />
            <input type="email" placeholder="email" value="<?php echo Input::get('email'); ?>" name="email" autocomplete="off" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="choose password" value="<?php echo Input::get('password'); ?>" name="password" autocomplete="off" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="confirm password" value="<?php echo Input::get('password_again'); ?>" name="password_again" autocomplete="off" />
            <span class="gen-sel">
                <input type="radio" name="gen" value="male" id="male" />
                <label for="male" class="fa fa-male"> male</label>
                <input type="radio" name="gen" value="female" id="female" />
                <label for="female" class="fa fa-female"> female</label>
            </span>
            <button class="btn right" type="submit" name="submit_register">Register</button>
            <span>Already signed up? <a href="login.php">click here</a> to login</span>
        </form>
```

Input.php which is a class to check whether an input is submitted or not:

```
<?php

class Input
{
    public static function exists($type = 'post'){
        switch($type){
            case 'post':
                return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
                break;

            case 'get':
                return (!empty($_GET)) ? true : false;
                break;

            default:
                return false;
                break;
        }
    }

    public static function get($item){
        if(isset($_POST[$item])){
            return $_POST[$item];
        } else if(isset($_GET[$item])){
            return $_GET[$item];
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

and the last file is Validate.php which is a class which has methods to validate the code (it is working properly for text input fields, i.e. email, text, password.):

```
public function check($source, $items = array()){
    foreach ($items as $item => $rules){
        foreach ($rules as $rule => $value){
            $value = $source[$item];
            if($rule === "required" && empty($value)){
                $this->addError( $item,"Marked field is required");
            } else{

            }
        }

        if(empty($this->_errors)){
            $this->passed = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

When I submit the form I get the following error for my text box:

> Notice: Undefined index: gen in /Users/Sammy/Sites/workspace/zen-cust/classes/Validation.php on line 16

which points towards this line of code in Validation.php:

```
$value = $source[$item];
```

I know, instead of selected code I have added huge chunks of code in here, but I am really not able to understand what is the fault over here!

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: can you show me how can you calling check method and what is $source, $items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking whether the value is present using `empty` function - which is correct - but you are doing it after trying to use it.  You should check first instead:

```
if($rule === "required" && empty($source[$item])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try to `var_dump` the `$source`, there you can see what all is in the `$source` array.

because the error is caused do to the fact that it can't find the index in the array `$source`